# how to put array with index and key inside a key for a request

Tags: java, node.js

```
   let todo = {
                template_id: 3213123,
                username: "test",
                password: "test",
                boxes[0][text]:"ddasd",          
   };
```

how to put `boxes[0][text]` in a key

Comment: You can create an array outside and push the objects with the field you want inside before assigning them to them, `boxes = [{  "text": "ddasd" }]`

Comment: `boxes : [{  "text": "ddasd" }]` should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it after you initialize the todo variable;

```
  let todo = {
                template_id: 3213123,
                username: "test",
                password: "test",         
   };
   
   todo[boxes[0][text]] = "ddasd"
```

Comment: todo[boxes[0][text]] = "ddasd"
                          ^

ReferenceError: text is not defined

Comment: Looks like you don't have a variable called "text"....did you mean to do `boxes[0]['text']` or better yet `boxes[0].text`?

Comment: i need like this for request
https://imgur.com/bP74apk

Comment: If your boxes variable looks like this.... `boxes = [{text:'someText' }]`, then change the line to this....  `todo[boxes[0].text] = "ddasd"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to define a key name using a variable. Example :

```
{
  [myVariable]: 'value',
}
```

---

```js
const boxes = [{
  foo: 'bar',
}];

const text = 'foo';

const todo = {
  template_id: 3213123,
  username: 'test',
  password: 'test',

  [boxes[0][text]]: 'ddasd',
};

console.log(todo);
```